# Error in Anchor Installation - cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor avm --locked --force. I'am using cargo to install AVM

Tags: hadoop-yarn, rust-cargo, solana, anchor-solana

error[E0793]: reference to packed field is unaligned
--> C:\Users\Kalyaan.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\ntapi-0.3.7\src\ntexapi.rs:2783:52
|
2783 |         *tick_count.QuadPart_mut() = read_volatile(&(*USER_SHARED_DATA).u.TickCountQuad);
|                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|
= note: fields of packed structs are not properly aligned, and creating a misaligned reference is undefined behavior (even if that reference is never dereferenced)
= help: copy the field contents to a local variable, or replace the reference with a raw pointer and use `read_unaligned`/`write_unaligned` (loads and stores via `*p` must be properly aligned even when using raw pointers)

error[E0793]: reference to packed field is unaligned
--> C:\Users\Kalyaan.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\ntapi-0.3.7\src\ntexapi.rs:2807:25
|
2807 |         ((read_volatile(&(*USER_SHARED_DATA).u.TickCountQuad)
|                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|
= note: fields of packed structs are not properly aligned, and creating a misaligned reference is undefined behavior (even if that reference is never dereferenced)
= help: copy the field contents to a local variable, or replace the reference with a raw pointer and use `read_unaligned`/`write_unaligned` (loads and stores via `*p` must be properly aligned even when using raw pointers)

Compiling is-terminal v0.4.7
Compiling http-body v0.4.5
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0793`.
error: could not compile `ntapi` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `avm v0.28.0 (https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor#b5519a65)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\Kalyaan\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installqzCRQ3`

I tried re-installing yarn and rust again, but th[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/869Yj.png)e problem still seems to persist.